# How can I prevent my code from yielding every frame?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, coroutine, yield-return

I am calling a method that call itself to crawl through terrain and create zones. However when the zones become to large the process ends in a stack overflow. By forcing the code to yield and take its time it finishes to completion successfuly and crawls the 3 zones in my map. However the method I am using is yielding EVERY single frame and I don't know how to make it yield just every 100 frames, causing it to be extremely slow to finish. Here is the pseudo code of what I am doing for readability:

```
 
public int timer = 0;
 
void Awake(){
 
StartCoroutine(crA);
}
 
public IEnumerator crA(){
//stuff
 
yield return StartCoroutine(crB());
 
//stuff that needs to happen only after crB finishes
}
 
public IEnumerator crB(){
 
timer = 0;
 
yield return StartCoroutine(crC());
 
}
 
public IEnumerator crC(){
//Crawiling code, crawls terrain to create a zone
 
if(x){ yield break;}
 
timer++;
 
//vv I WANTED IT TO YIELD ONLY IN HERE
if (timer ==100){
timer = 0;
yield return null;
}
//^^
 
yield return StartCoroutine(crC());
yield return StartCoroutine(crC());
yield return StartCoroutine(crC());
yield return StartCoroutine(crC());
yield return StartCoroutine(crC());
 
}
```

it seems yield return startcoroutine is causing a yield but I don't know what to use instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As soon as you call `yield` it will at least yield for one frame! So how can you avoid it -> by not using `yield` but something different e.g. a `Timer`

Comment: @derHugo could you give me an example of how I could do that? Btw what I am doing in this code is checking all adjacent cells in a 3d grid, west north east south up and down, recursively, Im not sure how I can pace this without the coroutine

Comment: Also what is the sense of skipping `every 100 frames` .. that is not how a Coroutine works .. a Coroutine is moved forward to the next `yield` every frame. If you don't `yield` it rather is executed everything within one single frame until you `yield` somewhere. Is you goal rather skipping to the next frame when a certain time has passed?

Comment: I think it would help to have your actual code and not only that pseudo ;)

Comment: @derHugo what I want is to yield once every 100 passes of recursive processing, since the code is crashing without it

Comment: I see, still I would not make it count but rather time based so you achieve a desired target frame rate

Comment: @derHugo Well I would do it by time, but without knowing the syntax to call the method without yielding I find myself in quite some hardship since I can't do either =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in general as long as you use `yield` it will at least `yield` for one frame like

```
yield return null;
```

does.

What you could do instead is use the [`IEnumerator.MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) "manually" without yielding it. This is basically what the Unity coroutine is calling once per frame if you used `StartCoroutine`.

And then only yield when you want to do so. Given your pseudo code something like e.g.

```
private void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(crA);
}

public IEnumerator crA()
{
    //stuff

    yield return crB();

    //stuff that needs to happen only after crB finishes
}

public IEnumerator crB()
{ 
    timer = 0;

    // "Manually" run the routine instead of using Unity Coroutine interface
    var crc = crC();
    while(crc.MoveNext())
    {
        if(timer >= 100)
        {
            yield return null;
            timer = 0;
        }  
    } 
}

public IEnumerator crC()
{
    //Crawiling code, crawls terrain to create a zone

    if(x) yield break;

    timer++;

    yield return crC();
    yield return crC();
    yield return crC();
    yield return crC();
    yield return crC();
}
```

And then as said you could do it time based instead of using a frame/call counter rather using e.g. a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch)

```
private const float TARGET_FRAMERATE = 60;

public IEnumerator crB()
{ 
    var targetMilliseconds = 1000f / TARGET_FRAMERATE;
    var sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.Start();

    // "Manually" run the routine instead of using Unity Coroutine interface
    var crc = crC();
    while(crc.MoveNext())
    {
        if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= targetMilliseconds)
        {
            yield return null;
            sw.Restart();
        }  
    } 
}
```

So whenever the last execution exceeded the target frame-rate it will yield one frame. You'll have to play a bit with the value .. probably something like 30 or even 24 might already be enough depending on your usecase.

It basically is a tradeoff between frame-rate and actual realtime duration.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: I did not know about this manual method with movenext() please allow me some time to try it out, it sounds promising

Comment: it wasnt working but then I replaced all the ```yield return crC();``` with ```    var crcX = crC();
    while(crcX.MoveNext())
    {
        if(timer >= 100)
        {
            yield return null;
            timer = 0;
        }  
    } ``` and crcY crcZ and it worked like magic, it doesnt show my debug logs so I have no idea why its working but it somehow is