# How can I search through a grid without recursion?

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, grid, cell

I'm trying to create areas by starting from 1 cell in a 3d grid byte array and going through every adjacent cell, if the cell value is 1 is added to the group, if it is not or it has already been checked then it is not. The method is supposed to run until it hits a dead end ( no more cells to search)

I am doing this using a recursive method but the size of the area I am searching through is too large and it is causing a stack overflow. I have managed to make the recursion happen only once per frame and it runs to completion successfully, so it is not an infinite loop, but this slows down the process too much so I was wondering if anyone could point me to a better method of achieving this.

Here is the current code, please assume for simplicity that this code will never reach the bounds of the array being searched:

```
public byte[,,] grid;
public Hashset<vector3Int> area;
public Hashset<vector3Int> Hchecked;
public vector3int origin;



public void start(vector3 orig){

Hchecked = new Hashset<vector3Int>();
searchPosition(orig,Hchecked);

}

public void searchPosition(vector3 pos,Hashset checked){

if(checked.Contains(pos)){return;}

checked.Add(pos);

if(grid[pos.x,pos.y,pos.z]==1){area.Add(pos);}else{return;}

searchPosition(new vector3int(pos.x-1,pos.y,pos.z),checked);
searchPosition(new vector3int(pos.x+1,pos.y,pos.z),checked);
searchPosition(new vector3int(pos.x,pos.y-1,pos.z),checked);
searchPosition(new vector3int(pos.x,pos.y+1,pos.z),checked);
searchPosition(new vector3int(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z-1),checked);
searchPosition(new vector3int(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z+1),checked);
}
```

Please let me know of an alternate way to do this or a way to step this so as to avoid a stack overflow when checking through large arrays

Comment: In some cases, you can replace recursion with use of the `Stack<T>` collection type. But even that will have limits. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, along with details about what you've tried so far to try to fix this, and what _specifically_ you need help with, it's not feasible to provide an answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho here is another question I posted with the alternate approach that works although it takes serveral minutes to process what should be a small area. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443429/how-can-i-prevent-my-code-from-yielding-every-frame